# Unable to parse json from api response

Tags: reactjs, json, parsing

I am able to see the clear response in console.

> {'timestamp': '2021-12-07 09:54:01.195543', 'Operating Parameters':
> {'quality_control': 'Action Needed', 'tool_status': 'running',
> 'message': {'Resurvey': {'Survey Environment': 'Flow higher than
> threshold', 'Recommended Action': 'Modify pumps shutoff sequence'}}},
> 'Sensor Data': {'bit_depth': '772', 'inclination': '37.83', 'azimuth':
> '299.86', 'gravity_toolface': '11.43', 'survey': {'survey_counter':
> '140', 'survey_time': '2021-12-07 09:54:01.195520'},
> 'previous_survey': {'previous_survey_depth': '1111',
> 'previous_survey_time': '2021-12-07 09:54:01.195539'}}}

but when i try to fetch the `timestamp` its printing undefined in console

```
  console.log("timestamp", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jobDetails)).timestamp);
```

Comment: Why are you `stringify`-ing the `jobDetails` variable? I suspect it works just fine if you leave that out.

Comment: i tried but its printing undefined in console

Comment: can you show how you are fetching the data

Comment: i am using socket. it will messup the question. the only problem is parsing the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that [`JSON.parse` doesn't accept single qoutes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#json.parse_does_not_allow_single_quotes). The best way to solve this is to change your backend implementation to something [compliant with the JSON spec](http://www.json.org/json-en.html). If that isn't possible, you could do something like this, but note that this is quite a fragile solution.

```js
const jobListings = "{'timestamp': '2021-12-07 09:54:01.195543', 'Operating Parameters': {'quality_control': 'Action Needed', 'tool_status': 'running', 'message': {'Resurvey': {'Survey Environment': 'Flow higher than threshold', 'Recommended Action': 'Modify pumps shutoff sequence'}}}, 'Sensor Data': {'bit_depth': '772', 'inclination': '37.83', 'azimuth': '299.86', 'gravity_toolface': '11.43', 'survey': {'survey_counter': '140', 'survey_time': '2021-12-07 09:54:01.195520'}, 'previous_survey': {'previous_survey_depth': '1111', 'previous_survey_time': '2021-12-07 09:54:01.195539'}}}"
const jsonJobListings = jobListings.replace(/'/g, '"')
const objJobListings = JSON.parse(jsonJobListings)
console.log(objJobListings.timestamp) // "2021-12-07 09:54:01.195543"
```

Comment: double thanks @cerebralFart